# estimated variance calculation with numpy cause an invalid value encountered error

Tags: python, numpy, plotnine

When trying to calculate the sample mean of some data, based on the number of samples (first for 1 sample, then for 2 and so on...)
I encounter this problem:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:3584: RuntimeWarning: Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice
  **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:209: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)
```

while  using numpy function "np.var()" on a data array.

my only function is this one:

```
def estimate_var(lam, n):
    np.random.seed(7)
    data = np.random.exponential(scale=1/lam, size=n)
    new_data = [np.var(data[:index + 1], ddof=1) for index in range(len(data))]
    return new_data
```

(THE 4th line causes the problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not an error it is a warning. You are getting the warning because you are taking the variance (`np.var`) of an array which has only 1 value which does not exist.

When `index=0` at the start of your list comprehension you are taking the variance of `data[:0+1]` which is just a single value.

If you want to take the variance of the data then just do `np.var(data)`